# Compare Two Excel Sheets – Highlight Differences – Macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
Sub test()
Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Set varSheetA = Sheet1

strRangeToCheck = "A1:B65536"
' If you know the data will only be in a smaller range, reduce the size of the ranges above.
Debug.Print Now
varSheetA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck)
varSheetB = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(strRangeToCheck) ' or whatever your other sheet is.
Debug.Print Now

For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
        If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
            ' Cells are identical.
            ' Do nothing.
        Else
            ' Cells are different.
            ' Code goes here for whatever it is you want to do.   
        End If
    Next iCol
Next iRow
End Sub
```

Please find the above code.
I need to highlight the different cells. I tried as mentioned below comments issue has not resolved. Please any one help me on this!

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).
 Please read [ask] and include an error description along with your [attempt to solve your issue](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and ask a question: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way.

```
Sub CheckTwoSheetsAndHighlightDifferences()
    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim mydiff As Integer
    Dim shtSheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim shtSheet2 As Worksheet
    Set shtSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    For Each mycell In shtSheet2.UsedRange
      If Not mycell.Value = shtSheet1.Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
        mycell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        mydiffs = mydiffs + 1
      End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

varSheetA is an array that holds the values of the range, it doesn't know of the cells on the sheet.

(If varSheetA should be the range then you would have to write `set varSheetA = ...` plus defining the variable as range)

```
worksheets("Sheet1").cells(iRow, iCol).color = vbRed
```

should work

BTW: it is much easier for us to help if you post the code itself and not a picture - how else should we "take the code"?

Comment: Sorry I try upload the full its not uploading.

Now I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
varSheetA(iRow, iCol).Color = RGB(0,255,0)
```

When you take into account that 255,0,0 is red and 0,255,0 is green, that should be very visible.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I used the above code but not work.

Run-time error '424':
Object required

Comment: ... but it's in the same loop as your code, how is it possible that it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes! That is why i am searching where is the exact issue.

Comment: or else you can take the code from above picture and try to run the code

Comment: @Dominique cannot work because `varSheetA` is an array of values and declared as `Variant` and valuse do not have a `.Color`. That is not a `Range` object.

Comment: Then what is the correct code.

Comment: @PEH Thanks for the explain to us. can you please share the code with work correctly.

Comment: Take a look at my answer - there you find correct code.